# Eye-dropper like tool for texture of trail

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, texture, eyedropper

[image]

I'd like to be able to 'draw' more of the trail that can be seen in the above picture in between the two trees.
I'm doing data augmentation for ML, so I want to have the same features but maybe add another one in a different direction for example, with a loop etc...

Is there some sort of tool (something similar to the eyedropper), where I could have a pen that would draw this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a custom brush for this.  Using a small part of the image, adjust the curves to create more contrast, and convert to black and white, erase any extraneous pixels. Define this as a brush. And apply settings similar to those shown below.

[image]

Back in your image, select a suitable foreground colour, set the brush size accordingly, and paint with the brush.

Example edit

[image]

Comment: Thanks @BillyKerr this is exactly what I needed! 
I've been trying to do the custom brush but I'm struggling to get it anywhere as good as what you did - I've barely ever used photoshop before.
Is there a way you could send me the brush as a package to download?
Thank you in advance
Cyril

Comment: All you need is [the brush image](https://imgur.com/V1mMHxO) since I've already given you the settings to apply.

Comment: ah yes sorry didn't see that you had also added this. Very helpful thank you!!